# Jupyter doesn't show full message when using Pandas

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

When working in Jupyter Notebook sometimes very long posts in a column get cut off and I have to scroll sideways to see the entire post which is very awkward to read and I want the whole post to be seen without scrolling.

I use the following options in Pandas:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None, 'display.max_rows', None)
```

I've also tried adding `('display.max_colwidth', None)` to the set_option and the result is the same, so I'm assuming it's a Jupyter issue and not a Pandas issue.

The height of the row has nothing to do either because there are messages with many more lines that are also cut in this way.

How can I correct this display problem?[image]

Comment: I just used:  pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)   and works sometimes, but it does not the solution.

Comment: You can pipe this (or typecast it) into something else in Python form that won't trigger the handling that works for most people. Because you fail to provide a toy example of a minimal, reproducible example (MRE) as advised in [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), I cannot easily run this and give you an option, or possibly a few options.

Comment: Wayne, the process is simple: I extract data from a mongodb collection that contains information on web pages (URL, message, other fields), this makes it a dataframe to show me the records. There is no special line of code except for the filter that uses to display the information on the screen:

df2[(df2['message'].str.contains(r'word1|word2|word3', case = False)) & (~df2 ['message'].str.contains(r'word4|word5|word6', case = False))].head(200)

Comment: That's still not something easily shared. So it doesn't really convey your issue to others reading your post. You are looking for a toy example that you can use a few lines of universal code to share. For example, if you make a dictionary where you fill the value with a long text using [lorem-text](https://pypi.org/project/lorem-text/) with `lorem.paragraphs(paragraph_length)` and then convert that to a pandas dataframe, does it show the problematic behavior you see?